# kubernetes - replace existing container at regular interval (5 to 10 minutes)

Tags: kubernetes, upgrade

At regular interval (usually 5 to 10 minutes) service recvs a api call to ask it reload its dataset , after receving this request , the app waits for all existing calls to finish , then it loads the new data and start accepting new traffic (Have no control over how many active requests are there, so it may take a lot of time.

What i am thinking is --- A service has always 2 container (for availability) , we create 2 containers with new dataset and when they are ready , the existing containers are shut down - is it a good way ? Something like a rolling

We can have around 100 of these services, any suggestions are welcome

Comment: sounds like you want a sidecar container to do that for you?